# What is a substochastic measure?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, definition

I read this from Huber's "Robust Statistics" p76. I cannot find the definition anywhere. I can only find the definition of a substochastic matrix on the internet. Huber did not provide a definition in his book.

---Edit---

I finally found the definition. This is a probability measure that puts nonzero mass at $\pm\infty$. Could someone tell me what type of distributions behave like this?

[image]

Comment: A (positive) measure with total mass $\le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise, a substochastic measure $\mathbb P$ on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ would be a map $2^{\mathcal F}:\to[0,1]$ satisfying the usual properties of a measure, with one alteration:

- $\mathbb P(E)\geqslant 0$ for all $E\in\mathcal F$.
- $\mathbb P(\varnothing)=0$.
- If $E_i$ is a disjoint sequence of sets in $\mathcal F$ then $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb P(E_i)$.
- The difference is that we need not have $\mathbb P(\Omega)=1$.